# How can I access ASP default properties from project classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a class that tries to access the options of the web app, but fails to compile during Run or Debug.

CS0122: 'IBBFCP.Properties.Settings'  no es accesible debido un su Nivel de Protección
(It is not accessible due to its protection level)

The code is very simple and will only publish important parts:

```
public class HelperFideicomiso : IDisposable
{
    private String Url
    {
        get
        {
           return global::IBBFCP.Properties.Settings.Default.WSLA_FideicomisoEndpointURL;
        }
    }
}
```

The project compile but fail running.

The property is well constructed by the Visual Studio 2005 IDE and value stored in `Web.config`

The class is internal to the project, there is no reference or DLL involved.

Thanks.

**Update: 08/14**

Simplifying the stage. After creating a web application, define a property and reference it from a page and a class get the same error:

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = WebApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;
        this.Label2.Text = new Configuracion().Setting;
    }
}
```

Referenced class. This class *fail*:

```
internal class Configuracion
{
    public string Setting = WebApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answare I found: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your project, expand Properties and double click on the Settings.settings file.  This will open it.  Look at the top in the toolbar, and change the Access Modifier to Public.

Comment: Thanks,  There is no Access Modifier option there. This is the Default Application Setting (ASP Web Application using .Net 2.0). The class already has internal access `namespace IBBFCP.Properties {
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {`, the property too `public string WSLA_FideicomisoEndpointURL {`